# Separation of Django view and template

Tags: django, django-urls

For example, I have 2 pages listing news, one for desktop, one for mobile, the urls are 'news/list' and 'news/mobile/list'. Assume the logic of getting news from model is same.

Currently, I work in this way.

```
def mobile_list(request):
    complexLogic()
    return render(request, 'app/mobile/list.html', context)

def list(request):
    complexLogic()
    return render(request, 'app/list.html', context)
```

I am thinking how to do something like the following. Is it currently supported in Django?

views.py

```
def list(request):
    complexLogic()
    return request,'success',context
```

urls.py:

```
('news/list', 'app.views.list', {'success' : 'app/list.html'}),
('news/mobile/list', 'app.views.list', {'success' : 'app/mobile/list.html'})
```

Comment: I would argue that you should look into responsive design instead of doing this. It would fix most of your problems and make your application more future safe.

Comment: Your advice is good. However, I just want to separate concerns. The problem may be more generic.

Comment: I would think you could use `request.path` and look for `mobile`. If it exists then show the mobile version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's supported. You can read about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions).

Basically, you want to add a `success` parameter to your `list` function, and then use that value:

```
def list(request, success):
    complexLogic()
    return render(request, success, context)
```

Comment: so how about this case {'success':'app/list.html','fail':'app/error.html'}, it seems the function signature would become longer for more outcomes